# Git Bash Slow Over Network Drive

Tags: git-bash

I'm having issues with Git Bash running slowly over a network drive. Something as simple as cd takes several seconds, moving forwards or backwards in Vim has a few seconds of latency, etc. This does not happen when I'm using git bash on a local drive. I also do not have this issue when using Windows' built in Command Prompt on either local or network drives. Any ideas on how to fix the latency issues?